# Interface for Equality-By-Value that doesn't change out of box behavior?

Tags: c#, equality

Okay, I'm reading up on all the advice on how to override object.Equals and == for value and reference types. In short, always override equality for structs and don't override equality for Reference types unless you have some unusual circumstance like class that wraps a single string. (But don't make a struct unless it is small, even if semantically or DDD terms it is a value type)

But most of my types that hold data are DTOS-- classes with lots of properties. They have more properties that is suitable for a struct (more than 16 bytes) and will be consumed by developers who will expect == and object.Equals to behave as usual.  All three scenarios come up-- needing to check for equality by reference, value (especially in unit testing) and by key (especially when working with data that came from or is going to a relational database.)

Is there a .NET framework way to implement equality-by-value or equality-by-key without stomping the default behavior of object.Equals? Or must I create my own ad hoc interface, like `ISameByValue<T>`, `ISameByKey<T>`?

Comment: Maybe you need IEqualityComparer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You could just expose your own comparer so the client of your library can use it at his leisure.  And don't hesitate to put your foot down, the bigger the class, the less likely client code should be creating duplicate objects.  Having no access to a comparer might well make him do the Right Thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `IEqualityComparer` types.  This allows you to create any number of different types capable of comparing your object by any number of different definitions of equality, all without changing any behavior on the type itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where I had implemented property based comparisons in the overridden `Equals` method (to implement `HasChanges` type functionality), but it caused all sorts of problems when I updated property values of items in a collection.

My solution (found by helpful users of this website) was to move the property based comparisons into a new, custom method and to return the default `object.Equals` value instead. However, this meant that there was no longer any based comparisons when calling the `Equals` method.

The solution was then to provide custom implementations of the [`IEqualityComparer<T>` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and to pass the instances through to any methods that require object comparisons, like the `IEnumerable Intersect` or `Except` methods for example:

```
if (digitalServiceProvider.PriceTiers[index].Territories.Count > 0 && 
    digitalServiceProvider.PriceTiers[index].Territories.Intersect(
    release.TerritorialRights, new CountryEqualityComparer()).Count() == 0) { ... }
```